# Unable to load the repository(PyDev for eclipse)

Tags: python, eclipse, repository, pydev

I encountered the problem. When i am trying to create new PyDev project, an error occurs:

Error:

```
Unable to load the repository http://pydev.org/updates 

Unknown Host: http://pydev.org/updates/content.xml
```

When I open this link(http://pydev.org/updates) in my browser, it redirects me here - http://pydev.org/updates/content.xml

So i understand Eclipse cannot find the repository because there's nothing to look at this link... Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

**Update:**
I installed PyDev as described at [PyDev Manual](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) (Help-Install New software-and so on...)

Comment: Weird, [http://pydev.org/updates](http://pydev.org/updates) redirects me to [http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/site.xml](http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/site.xml).

Comment: Actually, it does not redirect, but the page (http://pydev.org/updates ) says in browser: `Nothing to see here (this is just a dummy link to be redirected to http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/site.xml)`

Comment: Turn off firewall this might help.

Comment: For me I am unable to open the URL : https://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html ?

Answer (score 25):

If the url doesn't work directly, you may visit the update site in the browser (i.e.: http://www.pydev.org/updates/) and check the note to where it does redirect.

The current url it redirects to is http://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/5.8.0/ but it changes at each release, so, you may want to check the current release and update the version accordingly.

For older versions, it's possible to visit (in the browser) http://www.pydev.org/update_sites/ and check the existing update site urls (again, you may visit the update site url to see where it does redirect to and use that directly).

Notes:

- the redirects are to https, but some users seem to experience issues with it, so, using http may be an option.
- check your firewall to see if it's not blocking eclipse.
- if you're under a vpn, you may want to check if it's blocking something (i.e.: maybe try without the vpn).

Comment: I tried the latter, and received no error, but repeatedly no updates either, even if the `/site.xml` was removed. After fiddling with it, the former eventually worked. Remember to run Eclipse as Administrator if using Windows. Also, for some reason, CDT was set to get updates for Kepler, but Eclipse version was Luna, so enabled CDT 8.6 and found another update. Pay close attention to which update sites are enabled for the plugins.

Comment: I've referenced this comment over 5 times in the last year. The official channel for installing PyDev in Eclipse never works for me. +1

Comment: Please, DO NOT do that... the link from amazon is old, no longer kept and outdated!!! If you want, you can always visit `http://www.pydev.org/updates` and check what's the link it points to -- right now it's `https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/4.5.4`, and it changes at each release.

Comment: http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/site.xml works perfectly fine. Plus, it fetches the latest version (in my case, v5.0)

Answer (score 6):

Now http://www.pydev.org/updates points to current version of Pyded: https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/5.3.1/

But this link won't work unless you change the protocol to `http` instead of `https`. So, the working link is:

http://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/5.3.1/

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem. I was behind a proxy and once i set the proxy (as described here: http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/) it worked.
Not sure if you have the same problem though.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/383228/601320) answer by [Sukupa91](https://askubuntu.com/users/192102/sukupa91):

> Go to Window --> Preference --> General --> Network Connection -->
>   select Direct from drop down!

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i will advice to check if your are on VPN or not , i was getting the error because i was on office VPN

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in pydev site, because I have installed it multiple times and now facing problem to install it.
[image]