# Unable to install pydev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am trying to install pydev through update site and eclipse marketplace but that's impossible.
When trying to install I receive the following message:
Unable to read repository at https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/latest/content.xml.

Looks like this file does not exist anymore on the repository.
Did somebody found a solution about that ?

Regards

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Mars .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load the repository(PyDev for eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714994/unable-to-load-the-repositorypydev-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 7):

I've run into the same issue. I found out that the link at the PyDev site http://www.pydev.org/updates is redirecting to https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/6.4.1. Using this link doesn't work for me, in Eclipse 4.7.3a. 
However, changing this link to http://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/6.4.1 solves my problems. Apparently, there is an issue with the SSL redirection at the distribution site, or the https downloads in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

### The Error Message

I am note sure why you are getting an error message about `content.xml`, the real file that Eclipse should be reading is `content.jar` which is there.

Try one of the solutions below and please post more details if you can.

### Online Install

The URL for installation of the feature is http://pydev.org/updates. You can use that URL to *Install New Software...* from the *Help* menu if the Eclipse Marketplace is not doing what you want.

### Offline Install

If you meet the requirements (below) and continue to have problems with the update site, you can download to install offline. Get it from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/) (or follow the link from PyDev's [website](http://www.pydev.org/download.html) to SourceForge)

### LiClipse

Alternatively, simply get [LiClipse](http://www.liclipse.com/) instead. It is Eclipse and PyDev and a bunch of other useful stuff already packaged together. It is provided by the author of PyDev, so should give you the best experience.

### Minimum Eclipse and JVM Requirement

Double-check you meet the minimum requirements: [PyDev requires Java 1.7 or greater and Eclipse 3.8/4.3 or greater](http://www.pydev.org/download.html):

> **Requirements**
>
> Java 7:
>
> [...]
>
> Eclipse (3.8/4.3 onwards)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I don't know why it's searching for this file especially. I don't want to use liclipse as I have a lot more plugins on my install (cdt etc) and I prefer to build my dev platform from eclipse cdt vanilla. However I'm going to try what you propose and start from a fresh install. Maybe something in my workspace or preferences is triggering this issue

Comment: Fair enough, I couldn't tell if you were a new user to Eclipse or an experienced user, so I tried to answer for both. Did the offline install fail in your otherwise set up Eclipse BTW?

Comment: :)
I don't remember if I tried the offline install (I usually don't do this as it is sometimes hard to solve the dependencies). I've just tried it on another of my machines, and the install went well (from a clean install of Mars 1). I think I'm going to investigate the bad install on my other faulty machine and try to remove any personal files (workspace, preferences, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

At start i was also facing same error that : The solution is not provide while installing PyDev - Python IDE for Eclipse 6.3.2 
and when I am When trying to install I receive the following message: Unable to read repository at https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/latest/content.xml. ?

Then i came up with the final solution :

follow the steps :

**Online Install**

The URL for installation of the feature is http://pydev.org/updates. You can use that URL to Install New Software... from the Help menu if the Eclipse Marketplace is not doing what you want.

and uncheck all the options mentioned below on Install New Software Window like:
Uncheck :
1.Show only the latest versions of available software
2.Group Items by category
3.Show only software applicable to target environment
4.Contact all update sites during install to find required software

**Offline Install**

If you meet the requirements (below) and continue to have problems with the update site, you can download to install offline. Get it from SourceForge (or follow the link from PyDev's website to SourceForge).

- Download the latest zip from sourceforge
- Unzip it in any temp location
- In Eclipse: "Help->install new software"
- "Add" a new location to "Work with" "Local" button allows you to select the
  unzipped folder
- Give the location a name Back on the "install new
  software" dialog, select pydev, etc. and "finish" (Delete the zip and
  unzipped folder)

and uncheck all the options mentioned below on Install New Software Window like:
Uncheck :
1.Show only the latest versions of available software
2.Group Items by category
3.Show only software applicable to target environment
4.Contact all update sites during install to find required software

Answer (score 0):

To be a little more clear about an offline installation in eclipse neon:

- Download the latest zip from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/%20sourceforge)
- Unzip it in any temp location
- In Eclipse:  "Help->install new software"
- "Add" a new location to "Work with"
- "Local" button allows you to select the unzipped folder
- Give the location a name
- Back on the "install new software" dialog, select pydev, etc. and "finish"
- (Delete the zip and unzipped folder)

Answer (score 0):

The Error Message
I am note sure why you are getting an error message about content.xml, the real file that Eclipse should be reading is content.jar which is there.

Try one of the solutions below and please post more details if you can.

Online Install
The URL for installation of the feature is http://pydev.org/updates. You can use that URL to Install New Software... from the Help menu if the Eclipse Marketplace is not doing what you want.

Offline Install
If you meet the requirements (below) and continue to have problems with the update site, you can download to install offline. Get it from SourceForge (or follow the link from PyDev's website to SourceForge)

LiClipse
Alternatively, simply get LiClipse instead. It is Eclipse and PyDev and a bunch of other useful stuff already packaged together. It is provided by the author of PyDev, so should give you the best experience.

Minimum Eclipse and JVM Requirement
Double-check you meet the minimum requirements: PyDev requires Java 1.7 or greater and Eclipse 3.8/4.3 or greater: