# Getting "Unable to make member of class sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl" when installing PyDev in Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, pydev, eclipse-cdt

I've just installed an Xubuntu 16.04 64bit virtual machine in VirtualBox. I used the Eclipse Neon Installer and picked the CDT edition.

Right after I started Eclipse I also tried to install the PyDev from the Marketplace. Right after the dialog window where you select which sub-components you want to install (for example Mylyn integration) I got

> Unable to read repository at http://www.pydev.org/updates/content.xml.
>   Unable to make member of class sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl
>   accessible:  module java.base does not export sun.security.ssl to
>   unnamed module @7098b8f8

The underlying JDK is OpenJDK 9 (from the official repositories) and I have also tried switching to OpenJDK 8 (using `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and selecting the 8th version) with the same poor result. In addition I also have successfully installed PyDev in another machine that is using Xubuntu 16.10 (same architecture).

I was unable to find any hint on what's going on.

**EDIT:** Updating Eclipse works (I've just updated CDT which for whatever reason was not the latest version).

Comment: I also got this error on Ubuntu 16.04 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there's something wrong with the regular site. Perhaps because Source Forge [switched to Let's Encrypt](http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/blog/2016/12/02/plugins-install-issue/).

The best solution I found was to install PyDev [from a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5482776/4794).

1. Download the PyDev zip file from [Source Forge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/).
2. Unzip it, and copy the contents into Eclipse's `dropins` folder.
3. Restart Eclipse.

I wasn't sure exactly where the files were supposed to go, so here's the folder layout that worked for me:

- `eclipse`

  - `dropins`

    - `Eclipse X.Y.Z`

      - `features`

        - many folders
      - `plugins`

        - many folders

Before I got that working, I found another option on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468636/4794): use an [AWS mirror](http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/site.xml) for the PyDev update site. Unfortunately, the AWS mirror has an old version of PyDev.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer since it seems that it offers an reproducable solution. In my case I downloaded Eclipse Neon again, attempted a reinstall and it worked all of a sudden. Since in both cases I used the link for the regular site it and the procedure for the installation was the same it does point towards issues with the regular site.